# Updating an JList

Tags: java, swing

I've now made a JList which is based on an arraylist, and is being filled by the defaultlistmodel. The list will add people when they connect to the server, but it will not show the one connecting, or the ones connecting after. So, i have to update the JList.

My question is:

What should i be updating? Is it possible to use a timer which runs the update, or should i implement an updatemethod which runs when someone enters the server?

ps. This is an chatserver, much like IRC.

**Here is some of the code:**

**The GUI:**

```
jList2 = new javax.swing.JList();
try{
jList2.setModel(gl.getUsersOnlineAsDefaultListModel(gl.getClients())
    );
}catch(RemoteException ex){
    System.out.println(ex);
}
jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jList2);
```

The GUI Logic:

```
public DefaultListModel getUsersOnlineAsDefaultListModel(ArrayList<Client> clients) throws RemoteException {
DefaultListModel result = new DefaultListModel();
for(Client c : clients){
    result.addElement(c.findName());
}
    return result;
}

    public ArrayList<Client> getClients() throws RemoteException, NullPointerException{
            return cf.getClients();
    }
```

**The serverside:**

```
ArrayList clients = new ArrayList<Client>();

public ArrayList<Client> getClients(){
    return clients;          
}
```

Comment: So, i ended up using callback, which ran the updateJlist method i already had. Everything works great now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to do that is implementing a listener fired by the event the client enters the server which updates the JList.

Comment: That sounds great. I guess its some documentation out here on how to do that as well?

Comment: Is it possible to "listen" on the arraylist, and if a client gets added, ill update the JList?

Answer (score 3):

> What should i be updating?

The list model (`DefaultListModel`) that provides the content of the `JList`.

> Is it possible to use a timer which runs the update, or should i implement an updatemethod which runs when someone enters the server?

The second option sounds better.

Comment: Thanks :) I figure ill have to do some research

Answer (score 3):

Swing is single threaded; you have to accept that all changes to the Swing GUI must be done on the [EventDispatchThread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), including updates to your `XxxListModel`. Your code shows `RemoteXxx`, then you invoke a potentially long running thread from some of `Listeners` or (as you asked) from `Timer`. Basically you have two choices:

1) Implement the required methods of [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html): `publish()` invoked on the background htread, and `process()` and `done() invoked on the EDT.

2) Wrap execution in a `Runnble#Thread`, but then all output to the GUI must be wrapped into `invokeLater / invokeAndWait`, including thread safe methods `setText`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for that.

Is this what you're thinking about http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml?